# how to make .net core running on an ubuntu machine connect with the local database

Tags: c#, mysql, .net-core

I have a .net core program running on ubuntu, and I need to add a connection to the database running on the same machine.

I created a test program on my windows machine which connected to and interacted with the database and tables I want perfectly (via a putty tunnel), but used `MySql.Data.MySqlClient`, which it would seems is windows specific. I copied the `connection.cs` code up to the ubuntu server (changed the namespace, referenced it it the main program etc.). When i try to build, it can't find `MySql.Data.MySqlClient` (type or namespace error on mysql).

Is getting it working a matter of a) loading `MySql.Data.MySqlClient` into the ubuntu machine, b) using a different package (if so does anyone know what) or c) doing it a totally different way.

I have tried looking at tutorials/ other SO posts to see their code but none of them are about connecting to a normal db hosted on the same machine.

Comment: All of the tutorials show how to connect to a database. You need to provide the correct IP address - 127.0.0.1 or localhost. In fact, I'd bet most tutorials use just that

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos the problem is not the connection itself, but the missing .dll becase the PO is coding in ubuntu and the references does not exist

Comment: do please paste a link, all the tutorials i can find show connecting to an 'in-memory database'

Comment: @Simo in which case the OP should explain which package was added, if any.

Comment: `MySql.Data.MySqlClient` is NOT Windows specific. It's a NuGet package that you need to install to the project if you want to use that DLL. You cannot just copy random files and expect everything to work

Comment: I thought the build process would bring in referenced packages if they were shown as 'using bla bla'

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto so rude...

Comment: @Simo Not rude, but on point.

Comment: @Louise First three https://mysql-net.github.io/MySqlConnector/tutorials/net-core-mvc/ https://insidemysql.com/getting-started-with-asp-net-core-and-mysql-connectornet/ https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-connect-mysql-with-asp-net-core/

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto _You cannot just copy random files and expect everything to work_  it wasn't on point, it was pointless to be so rude

Comment: @Simo it's not rude. There aren't many ways to say "Don't try to add code or references until something works, read the docs, understand what each thing does"

Comment: Thank you Camilio Trentavino, i'm busy trying to get nuget to add the package (so thank you everyone, the answer to my question was (a) you can download the package on ubuntu).  if you want to put that is as an answer, i will accept it.

Answer (score 2):

Shamelessly copypasta'd from https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-programming-connecting-connection-string.html

```
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection conn;
string myConnectionString;

myConnectionString = "server=127.0.0.1;uid=root;" +
    "pwd=12345;database=test";

try
{
    conn = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection();
    conn.ConnectionString = myConnectionString;
    conn.Open();
}
catch (MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

You do need to install MySQLClient on your ubuntu machine if it's not there already. Just select it in your package manager.

Also, if this doesn't work, verify that mysql is actually listening on a TCP port. It's possible that you're attempting a TCP connection but its actually listening on a socket.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/can-not-connect-to-server.html

Comment: It is running on linux and MySql.Data.MySqlClient.dll doesn't exist

Comment: Any explanation why this is your answer?

Comment: @nilsK yes but this isn't the answer to the PO's question.

Comment: @Simo was not addressed to you. You just posted two seconds before I pushed the button ;)

Comment: @TerryCarmen are you sure that installing mysql on ubuntu will give to .net core the right references to open a connection? i don't think so...

Comment: @Simo the OP asked how to connect to the local machine. That's what this answers. In any case providers are added through packages, not direct references to DLLs.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos reading the PO's question I was pretty sure that the problem wasn't how to code the connection itself (full of tutorial about that) but how to download the right packages in order to add the references to mysql

Comment: @Simo not according to the title. Anyway, I hope you didn't downvote this because *this* is a correct answer for connecting to the local machine. As for adding the packages, that's not mentioned at all.

Comment: @Simo incidentally, the google results also show how to add the packages

Comment: @Simo The DB drivers should come with the .Net core or Mysql install (don't remember which). In any case the compiler will complain about any missing packages and they can be added with Ubuntu's package manager.

Comment: As said by PO: _When i try to build, it can't find MySql.Data.MySqlClient_ so i was pretty sure that the problem is not the connection code, but the package!

Comment: @Simo which means the OP didn't add a package at all but tried to find something, somewhere. The OP didn't even explain what packages was added, which forces people to guess

Comment: thank you so much everyone, this has been so helpful. sorry if i didnt explain it properly and caused com fusion

Comment: @Louise go to `Nuget.org` and check which MySQL packages are available. The official one is [MySql.Data](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySql.Data/)